# How do you add APP_CFLAGS to an android makefile

Tags: android-studio, java-native-interface, makefile

I was able to successfully pass in APP_CFLAGS via eclipse through via the settings' ndk-build command as

```
ndk-build -B NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_CFLAGS=-DTEST
```

I have now switched to Android studio and was trying to do it directly in the makefile with the following, but its not taking:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
APP_CFLAGS += -DTEST
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= test.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

It builds fine, but my TEST variable is never set in the C++ code.

How can I add it to the makefile? 
Or, How can I add it to Android Studio project settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LOCAL_CFLAGS` for C/C++ code additional flags or `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` for C++ code in Android build system.

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DTEST=1
```